# Typescript/Angular 10: component with generic union type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```js
export interface Channel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface TvChannel extends Channel {
  subscribed: boolean;
}

export interface RadioChannel extends Channel {
  // marker interface to distinguish radio channels from TV channels
}
```

and an angular component:

```js
// ./channel.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'channel',
  templateUrl: './channel.html'
})
export class ChannelComponent<T extends TvChannel | RadioChannel> {
  @Input() channel: T;
  (...)
}
```

with the following template

```html
<!-- ./channel.html -->
<div>{{ channel.id }} </div>
<div *ngIf="channel.subscribed !== undefined">{{ channel.subscribed }} </div>
```

My problem is that I get compile errors on the template because `channel.subscribed` can not be resolved . I understand that it works for `channel.id` because that's the property found in both types `TvChannel` **and** `RadioChannel` (i.e. the intersection between those types). However I would like to have a component that can handle both types (i.e. the union of both types).

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a union like that - you end up with T being only types which are assignable to both TvChannel and RadioChannel. From your inheritance setup this is only going to be Channel.

You can handle this kind of behaviour with type guards - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html - you use a type guard to assert that your type is actually of one type or the other.

However, based on your code, I don't think this is the exact behaviour you're after.

You seem to want a union of the types - where properties that are unique to a specific type are optional, and the ones that are shared are as they are defined in Channel.

Here's how I'd type this. I've added property foo to RadioChannel to test that it's behaving correctly

Types:

```
export interface Channel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface TvChannel extends Channel {
  subscribed: boolean;
}

export interface RadioChannel extends Channel {
  // marker interface to distinguish radio channels from TV channels
  foo: string;
}
```

Helper types. The idea here is to construct two sets of keys. UniqueKeys<T, U> is the set of keys which only exist on one object or the other, but not on both. CommonKeys<T, U> is the opposite.

```
type UniqueKeys<T, U> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof U> | Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>;

// Test unique keys
type ChannelUniqueKeys = UniqueKeys<TvChannel, RadioChannel>; // "subscribed" | "foo"

type CommonKeys<T, U> = keyof T & keyof U;
// Test common keys
type ChannelCommonKeys = CommonKeys<TvChannel, RadioChannel>; // "id" | "name"
```

Now we reconstruct these back into object slices based on these two keysets, looking up the correct value from (T & U) - the combination of both types.

```js
type UniqueObjectSlice<T, U> = {[key in UniqueKeys<T, U>]: (T & U)[key]};
type CommonObjectSlice<T, U> = {[key in CommonKeys<T, U>]: (T & U)[key]};
```

Finally we can construct PartialUnion<T, U>. This is now simply the Partial (make all properties optional) of the unique object slice, combined with the common object slice:

```js
type PartialUnion<T, U> = Partial<UniqueObjectSlice<T, U>> & CommonObjectSlice<T, U>;
```

I've attached this to a function just to check it's working correctly - but just sub myComponent for your class and you should get the intended behaviour.

```js
function myComponent<T extends PartialUnion<TvChannel, RadioChannel>>(properties: T) {
    // Unique keys
    type foo = typeof properties.foo; // string | undefined
    type subscribed = typeof properties.subscribed; // boolean | undefined

    // Common keys
    type id = typeof properties.id; // number
    type name = typeof properties.name; // string
}
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQAtMklgAbOAbwCg5EATALjiQFcBbAIzQG47WmDsBYBnGFGQBzfgF8aNUJFiIUaLLjgAVAG5ESZSqFRIGogsVIVqA0Wy6jsknszhcIEcsBJyFS6PDIqBg4eABKmAwIEPpWRiAmZhYG1rT0APTpcByYUADWaKrBGngwEHBR4tJsCKKEcFCR0XDYlobm6FAQHNoAai1tFKIC6B5iEtK%20NDAAnmB4AKpICACObMAA0sAzogA8WgA0cAsAfHAAvHAAoiDY5GwMwLsFMxDo2kcvb8dnAD7Xt3uj2e22%20C0%20oPeWhO-BomW0wHEcDYyzWeBew1m82ScSWq3WWx2F2OqIJ2z2ulihiOESiMUG5BhcHhACI7A4nAgXCy4P8WaMICyFFi8PhuhwIEhCRSjqdiV8oXAAGRwBXHfjwrSI%20DYcWS1Xk6ZzUUMsUcCVS8nEs0W6X7PQMmlNekpRm8ZlZFkIBg8vlIITAIVG7F4tEAeS4ACtgNgYABlcgIXD7WVnS5UADaL1UJPxm3JKZ%20AF0WAAKLTK44ASiz2yLsn4IoIeqQEejsYTSaehx%20xMz2eQzfNkrtPdOJbg5crCxrL3rjeNcAACrkYAhMOQ8ZLC3LLivYOvyLtQ%20s2zH44nk2OTmcVTbJWeO5fu6n3Qp0CjY9EkNkZmbIGQKD7HAxjAKY5j7muG5bkg9pUhQTp0vBjInKWYBdPMB6IiwWhVjY9AZFkJ7ooaBFwE2ArEiK3zoRAmFroiAB0AruvC4iSEgUi8sipjAOgyDAAwAj0E27KOM4glUcaNEYWgDGiIxYmci4rFZO4njeD%20-woo8-FkEJwkekOFoGjshlNt6UnzDJdFyQgTHeqprCcDwUDmYu-rCFZwA2fR9kKZ5wBOex0g0LIQA)

Comment: Very good answer (and problem identification). Exactly the information I was looking for. Implemented my component with it and it works.